# How do I make an ML-estimation for a time-dependent Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose that I know that a random variable $X$ has the distribution

$X \sim \cases{\text{Bernoulli}(p_1)\ \ \text{if}\ \ t > t_0 \\ \text{Bernoulli}(p_2)\ \ \text{if}\ \ 0 < t < t_0 }$

and that I collect pairs of data $(x_i,\ t_i)$. How should I go about when trying to make maximum likelihood estimations of $p_1, p_2$, and $t_0$ — and is this even possible?

Also, I'm actually more interested in the case where I already know what $p_1$ and $p_2$ are and looking for an estimation of $t_0$ (with a confidence interval, if possible), but the more general case above has piqued my interest as well.

Comment: My first question is how X is distributed? For instace, what is $P\left(X\leq \frac{t_0}{2} \right)$?

Comment: @callculus42 $X$ is distributed as stated in the question. If $t>t_0$, $X  \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_1)$, and if $t_0 >t>0$, then $X  \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_2)$. I don't think the expression $P(X \le \frac{t_0}{2})$ makes sense in this case.

Comment: I suspect that the random variable is well defined. That's why I'm asking. Have you proved that? The term I've mentioned makes sense as for every random variable.

Comment: Hi @callculus42. $X$ follows the Bernoulli distribution so it can take the values $1$ and $0$, and I think I can define the probabilities as follows: $P(X=1) = H(t - t_0)p_1 + H(-t+t_0)p_2$ and $P(X=0) = H(t-t_0)(1-p_1) + H(-t+t_0)(1-p_2)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.